# Shortcuts to change the active tab in my application

Tags: c#, winforms, user-interface, keyboard-shortcuts

My application has a main window that contain a TabControl with about 7 TabItems. Inside each tabItem I put a UserControl.

I would like that (no matter the active tab, or control) when the user press a combination of keys then user-interface jumps to a specific tab. that is, The same behavior that Firefox: alt+1 goes to the first tab, alt+n goes to the N tab.

How can I achieve this? or... what should I start searching?

I can't show you any code because the problem is that I don't know how to start.

Thanks

Comment: I assume that you don't want to allow `Alt-42`.

Comment: +1 since this is apparently a non-trivial problem.

Comment: @Slacks: maybe, 'cause 42 is the Answer to Life, the Universe and Everything... and we don't know anything about the keyboards of the future. :D

Comment: @Jonathan: There's a reason I chose 42.  :)  By the way, SLaks doesn't have a `c`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Set the form's [`KeyPreview`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.keypreview.aspx) property to `true`, override the form's `OnKeyDown` (or `OnKeyUp`) method, and put in the following code: (Untested)

```
protected override void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e) {
    base.OnKeyDown(e);
    if (e.Alt && e.KeyCode > '0' && e.KeyCode <= '9') {
        tabControl.SelectedIndex = (int)(e.KeyCode - '1');
        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: Tested and working perfectly. I only changed e.KeyCode by e.KeyValue. Thanks.

Comment: since we override the form's `OnKeyDown` then `KeyDown` will not work anymore so if am I right how to make it with following short key sequence  `ctrl + 1,2,3...9` ?

Comment: @sam: You need to call the `base` method too.